Connection reset by peer issue and doubts about the idle connection timeout of AWS API Gateway & ALB?
All. We have deployed springboot services on ECS and use WebClient from spring-webflux, which uses Reactor Netty Clients under the hood, as the http client to call outside APIs.
So far, we just used the basic configuration to build the WebClient
@Bean 
public WebClient createWebClient(WebClient.Builder builder) {
    return builder.baseUrl("${placeholder4targetUrl}")
                    .build();
}

In one service (Service A), we use the internal ALB address as the target baseUrl, and it works fine.
But in another service (Service B), we use the AWS Gateway address as the target baseUrl for some internal reason. And we notice from logs that intermittenly calling the API will get a 'Connection rest by peer' error. If trying again immediately, it would call successfully. But if calling once again after some time, the error reappeared.
After some digging, I think the cause is that API Gateway might close the idle connection after some time（29 or 30 seconds?) Our client configuration doesn't specify idle connection timeout on client side, so when it tries to use the conenction that is closed by Gateway, it will have the 'reset by peer' error.
But this cannot explain why the Webclient in Service A that calls the ALB address never reports such error. I check that the ALB has configured 'Connection idle timeout' to 180 seconds. Yes it is longer than Gateway's 30s, but our services are for internal systems and there're only sporadical requests in a day,  so there are time intervals between calling that are definitely longer than a few hours. So why it doesn't report such error when the next call happens after a long time.
I notice that this ALB also has the configuration of 'HTTP client keepalive duration' to 3600 seconds/1 hour.  Will this affect the behaviour of the connection? But since we use basic config of WebClient without setting any keep-alive related info, we don't explictly have heartbeat or other mechanism to renew the connection. Could the frameworks has some lower-level mechanism to do so? But if that is the case, why Service B which calls the Gateways will have such issue?
I've made requests with both services at different time intervals and seen from the logs that the problems still exist.
